# Show that $X=F^{-1}(U)$ Cumulative distribution $F(x)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $F(x)$ be a cdf, and assume that that $U$~$uniform(0,1)$ Show that then  $X=F^{-1}(U)$ cumulative distribution $F(x)$.

$F(X)=1-k^{\theta}x^{-\theta}$ for $x>k$, $0$ otherwise

my initial thought is that we can let $F_U(U)$ be a cdf of $X=F(X)$ for every $U\in[0,1]$

$F_U(U)=P(X\leq U)$

I am not sure if this even the right way to do it.

Comment: What has to be shown? This is not clear.

Comment: What do you mean by $X$ cumulative distribution $F(x)$? Cumulative distribution is not a verb, it doesn't make sense to say an object cumulative distribution another object.

Comment: Sorry, showing that $X=F^{-1}(U)$ cumulative distribution $F(x)$

Comment: Do you mean that $F^{-1}(U)$ and $X$ have the same distribution? Look up the probability integral transformation; this is a standard trick.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, did not pay full attention that i forgot to add $X=F^{-1}(U)$

Comment: Yeah, so you want to show that $F^{-1}(U)$ has CDF $F$. This is the basis for the probability integral transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're asking for the general situation or for the specific cumulative distribution that you gave, but if the cumulative density of $X$, $F_X$, is invertible then $F_X^{-1}(U)$ and $X$ have the same distribution because
$$
P(F_X^{-1}(U) \leq x) = P(U \leq F_X(x)) = \int_0^{F_X(x)} 1 dx = F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)
$$
so they have the same cumulative density function.

Answer (score 0):

The cdf of $X$ is $P(X\le x)=P(U\le F(x))=F(x)$, as required. In the case $F=1-(k/x)^\theta$, $x=k(1-F)^{-1/\theta}$ with $F\sim U(0,\,1)$.